# What happens when you do not close an HBase table?

Tags: java, hbase

I am considering creating a HBase table when my application starts up and leaving it open as long as my application is running. My application may run indefinitely.

What happens if I never close the HBase table?

- Is there a maximum time the  connection can be open/idle before it need to be reinitialized?
- How is the connection closed if the system crashed?

I have *HBase The Definitive Guide* but I have not found the information I am looking for in there. If there are any online references for this then  please provide them.

Answer (score 2):

This was extracted from "HBase in Action" page 25:

> "Closing the table when you’re finished with it allows the underlying
>   connection resources to be returned to the pool."

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.ru/2012/09/hbase-client-timeouts.html) is about timeouts in HBase. Generally speaking, there is a lot of them:

- ZK session timeout (zookeeper.session.timeout)
- RPC timeout (hbase.rpc.timeout)
- RecoverableZookeeper retry count and retry wait (zookeeper.recovery.retry, zookeeper.recovery.retry.intervalmill)
- Client retry count and wait (hbase.client.retries.number, hbase.client.pause)

You may try to raise them a bit and set a really high value for retry count. This can make your sessions be alive for a very long period of time.

When the system of HBase client crashed, the connection is closed by timeout.